# Typescript: Extract the Generics from Class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extract/infer the generic from a class.

Searching on the internet brings me to the ExtractFunction below, but is not working as expected. The extracted is always `(...args: any) => any` instead of being the real type added to the real class.

```js
type ExtractFunction<T> = T extends BaseComponent<infer U> ? U : never;
abstract class BaseComponent<FUNCTION extends (...args:any) => any>{}
```

You can find an [example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAUQB5gE4EMDGYAiMA2MA5umDACYBiArgHbYCWA9rQDwAqAfHALxztwYKGLXIBnOACF0YmAGEmAWygsRYVg1oAzGKjgBVbgH4DcAFxxaMAG66A3KEz4ZE6bIXLVtdZX0A5OXYASQB5P0FhUQkACgA6ePRUIjEzdFoIAEpebjSITgBvAF9QEpAnF34YMVwCYlIKACUxJnxbOWcxCSEyKKkZeSUVK29WaPQLACMmFpg0gBo4CYtq1E0iLJ5uayYGcgLispZquCQLZDQsGsISMio6RhYOKqu626aWto6xTlAAel%204JgjmAThY4gkkik4LkNjl0n8AZJqCCgnAAO5pEFjSbTQjzRbLNBrWFwba7BZaVBKSrVPDXerkd6teRfUqgIA).

Do you have any suggestions to get this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `BaseComponent` class has no structural dependence on its type parameter, so inference will not work.  You need a property of type `FUNCTION` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/Wz7Lrw)) or something else that actually depends on it.  See [the TS FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  See the linked q/a for more info